# Objects not being passed correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

A waterfall function is being called, with one of the inside functions taking an array of user docs and trying to find if they are the user himself or a friend of the user. Based on these two things, I want to return the user docs each with "me" being true/false and "friend" being doc/false. The doc itself is not true. However, the result I am getting is incorrect.

Here is the code:

```
function(users, callback) {
   async.mapSeries([users], function(user, next) {
        Friend.findOne({userId: req.signedCookies.userid, friend_id: user}, function(err, friend) {
            var me = false;
            if (user.id === req.signedCookies.userid) {
                console.log('me check');
                me = true;
            }
            if (friend === undefined) {
                friend = false;
            }
            var object = {'user': user, 'friend': friend, 'me': me};
            //searchResults.push(object);
            next(err, object);
        });
    }, function(err, searchResults) {
        console.log(searchResults);
        callback(null, searchResults);
    });
}
```

This is the result that I'm getting:

```
[ { user:
     [ { firstName: 'test1',
         lastName: 'test1s',
         email: 'test1@gmail.com',
         emailTrue: 'test1@gmail.com',
         firstNameTrue: 'Test1',
         lastNameTrue: 'teST1s',
         password: '$2a$10$irIz5rVSFwGFVjzXqAqdxuxa8wAFoV99FulXykt
',
         phone: 2738483282,
         birthday: Tue Aug 22 823 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Dayli
         email_confirmed: true,
         date_created: Thu Aug 15 2013 14:54:17 GMT-0400 (Eastern
,
         _id: 520d23d9367604cc0d000001,
         __v: 0,
         socialAccounts: [],
         phoneList: [],
         emailList: [] },
       { firstName: 'test1',
         lastName: 'test1ss',
         email: 'test1s@gmail.com',
         emailTrue: 'test1s@gmail.com',
         firstNameTrue: 'test1',
         lastNameTrue: 'test1ss',
         password: '$2a$10$kaWYHkg68c4Uti6/DlNVR.N0Ojzo.RnsQ6BARTd
',
         phone: 888439348,
         birthday: Mon Aug 30 94 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylig
         email_confirmed: true,
         date_created: Thu Aug 15 2013 15:11:19 GMT-0400 (Eastern
,
         _id: 520d27d7a767bdbc1c000001,
         __v: 0,
         socialAccounts: [],
         phoneList: [],
         emailList: [] } ],
    friend: false,
    me: false } ]
```

Comment: Why are you passing `[users]` into `async.mapSeries` instead of just `users`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `users` directly into your `async.mapSeries` call instead of wrapping it in array brackets:

```
async.mapSeries(users, function(user, next) {
```